# Can pytest a file with invalid modules/packages Python name?

Tags: python, testing, module, pytest

I can run `python some.code.py` in cli.

But I can not run `pytest some.code.py` neither `pytest 'some.code.py'`.

The traceback error is

```
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/_pytest/python.py:501: in _importtestmodule
    mod = self.fspath.pyimport(ensuresyspath=importmode)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/py/_path/local.py:701: in pyimport
    __import__(modname)
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'some'
```

I understand that pytest import the file as a module so it does not accept invalid module name. But the file I'm testing is generated programmatically by another app. Is there a way to work around this constrain in pytest?

Comment: You could create a symlink to the file with an appropriately formed name.

Comment: how about, asking your app to generate all the files at a specific dir, and run `pytest` on that dir

Comment: There is no solution. Symlink won't work, subdirectory won't work. Rename the dots to underscores before running the test suite, or change the other app not to generate invalid module names.